# Can't start MySQL docker container with the -P option

Tags: docker

I was trying to run a docker container with mysql, exposing the 3306 port using:

```
docker run -P  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepw mysql:latest
```

But I get such an error:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 4a695272b96bf13c4f46c8bdde83955c149f2761cfbd8524d27b7054f823f054:  (exit status 1)
```

Does anybody know what is this all about and how do I investigate this problem?

Comment: Is something else listening on port 3306?

Comment: I had a running mysql instance before. But I stopped it and double checked there is nothing on a 3306 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the iptables rules. After starting docker container I ran `iptables-restore` which destroyed all the rules docker created.

After restarting `docker` service all rules came back and container now starts correctly.